# Filtering values by cell means in r

Tags: r, filtering

Here is a sample data frame I am working with:

```
ID, Item,   Condition,  Reaction Time
A,  X,      1,          4
A,  Y,      2,          7
A,  Z,      3,          5
B,  X,      2,          3
B,  Y,      3,          9
B,  Z,      1,          3
C,  X,      3,          2
C,  Y,      1,          7
C,  Z,      2,          11
D,  X,      1,          4
D,  Y,      2,          3
D,  Z,      3,          6
E,  X,      2,          3
E,  Y,      3,          6
E,  Z,      1,          2
F,  X,      3,          4
F,  Y,      1,          9
F,  Z,      2,          3
```

Participants were observed in an experiment where they were given three items each but the items were counterbalanced with three different conditions. So each participant were observed not only by their responses to different items but also to different conditions. I would like to trim the data by item and condition. That is, any observed reaction time that goes over 3 standard deviations from the mean by 3 SD, it should be filtered out. The sample mean and SD table by item and condition is below.

```
Means (SDs) of reaction time by item and condition
    Condition 1,    Condition 2,    Condition 3
Item X,     3 (1.1),        4 (1.1),        5 (0.4) 
Item Y,     4 (0.2),        3 (1.3),        2 (0.7) 
Item Z,     3 (0.4),        5 (0.3),        4 (1.3)
```

So, any observation that goes over 6.3 in a cell that is Item X and Condition 1 (which is not shown in the current data table) should be eliminated. Can anyone help me how to write a code for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` to accomplish this (see below). But I think you should reconsider whether you really want to remove observations more than 3 SD away from the mean. This artificially reduces the variance of the data. You might consider posting a separate, statistical question on CrossValidated.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Item, Condition) %>%
  filter(
    Reaction_Time >= mean(Reaction_Time) - 3 * sd(Reaction_Time),
    Reaction_Time <= mean(Reaction_Time) + 3 * sd(Reaction_Time)
    )
```

Or a more compact (but possibly harder to read version):

```
df %>%
  filter(
    abs((Reaction_Time - mean(Reaction_Time)) / sd(Reaction_Time)) <= 3
  )
```